# How to implement generic method with constraints

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics, constraints

from my title it might be a little hard to understand what I'm trying to achieve, so I'll go a little further into detail.

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IModelBuilder<T>
    where T : IStandardTemplateTemplate
{
    M Build<M>(T pTemplate, params object[] pParams) where M : BaseModel;
}
```

Now I want to implement the interface in my actual builder. The builder I use to map different object types. So this looks as follows:

```
public class BusinessModelBuilder : IModelBuilder<IBusinessTemplate>
{
    public virtual M Build<M>(IBusinessTemplate pTemplate, params object[] pParams) where M : BussinessModel
    {
        var businessModel = Activator.CreateInstance<M>();

        // map data

        return businessModel;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is the following. I can't get the constraint to work. Since I defined the constraint on the interface it won't let me use a different constraint on my actual method, even though my BusinessModel inherits from BaseModel. It keeps telling me my constraint M must match the constraint from the interface. I tried several different approaches, but none seem to work.

Does anyone know if or how this can be achieved? I just want to tell my constraint in the interface that inherited models are allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a short but complete example of your problem:

```
public class Parent { }
public class Child { }

public interface Interface
{
    void Foo<T>() where T : Parent;
}

public class Implementation : Interface
{
    public void Foo<T>() where T : Child
    {

    }
}
```

This won't compile, for the same reason that yours won't.  The implementation of the interface method must have the *exact same* constraint on the generic argument, it can't have a more restrictive constraint.

Your `Build` method can only constrain the type to `BaseModel`, not `BussinessModel`.

If you alter your `IModelBuilder` interface to add an additional class level generic argument, and then use *that* as the constraint, then you can get the desired functionality:

```
public interface IModelBuilder<T, Model>
    where T : IStandardTemplateTemplate
    where Model : BaseModel
{
    M Build<M>(T pTemplate, params object[] pParams) where M : Model;
}    

public class BusinessModelBuilder : IModelBuilder<IBusinessTemplate, BussinessModel>
{
    public virtual M Build<M>(IBusinessTemplate pTemplate, params object[] pParams)
        where M : BussinessModel
    {
        var businessModel = Activator.CreateInstance<M>();

        // map data

        return businessModel;
    }
}
```

This solution is based in part on [Reed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18152415/1159478) but which takes it a step further.

Comment: +1 This is great, if you need to be able to allow `BusinessModelBuilder` to also be generic.

Comment: Genius, that's exactly what I needed! Thanks so much, been trying to figure this one out for a while!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to put both in as class constraints:

```
public interface IModelBuilder<T, M>
    where T : IStandardTemplateTemplate
    where M : BaseModel
{
    M Build<M>(T pTemplate, params object[] pParams);
}
```

You can then use:

```
public class BusinessModelBuilder : IModelBuilder<IBusinessTemplate, BusinessModel>
{
   public virtual BusinessModel Build(IBusinessTemplate pTemplate, params object[] pParams)
   {
       //...
```

Comment: Note that in this case the return type of `Build` now must be `BusinessModel`, rather than some type that extends `BusinessModel`.

Comment: @Servy Yes, true - given that the class was `BusinessModelBuilder`, I am guessing that was the goal.  You could still return a type that subclasses `BusinessModel`, but the result would be a `BusinessModel` variable.

Comment: See my solution, which is a slight modification of yours, but handles the case I describe.

Answer (score 0):

You can define  your interface little bit differently to include  e.g.

```
public interface IModelBuilder<T,M>
    where T : IStandardTemplateTemplate
    where M: BaseModel
{
    M Build<M>(T pTemplate, params object[] pParams);
}
```

and use it like below

```
public class BusinessModelBuilder : IModelBuilder<IBusinessTemplate,BusinessModelBuilder>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the constraint is actually different, so it does not satisfy the interface.

```
IModelBuilder<IBusinessTemplate> sample = new BusinessModelBuilder();
sample.Build(??)
```

The compiler would be expecting the arguments to `Build` to be a `BaseModel`, but since you can have a type inheriting from `BaseModel` that is not a `BusinessModel`, this is obviously invalid.

Now, to get to the actual meat of the problem, you can solve this with another generic argument.

```
 public interface IModelBuilder<TemplateType, ConstraintType>
 {
     public ConstraintType Build<ConstraintType>(TemplateType template, params object[] parameters);
 }
```

Alternatively, you can switch things around and get some generic type inference if you really want to go crazy (assuming this is even applicable to your argument):

```
public interface IStandardTemplate<TModel> { }

public interface IModelBinder<TModel>
{
     TModel ApplyParameters(IStandardTemplate<TModel> template, params object[] parameters);
}

public class ModelBuilder
{
      public TModel Build<TModel>(IStandardTemplate<TModel> template, params object[] parameters)
      {
          var model = Activator.CreateInstance<TModel>();

          var modelBinder = ModelBinderFactory.CreateBinderFor(model);

          return modelBinder.ApplyParameters(template, parameters);
      }
}
```

Then you can simply make various ModelBinder classes and associate them in your factory.

Example call:

```
  public class BusinessTemplate : IStandardTemplate<BusinessModel> { }

  var businessTemplate = new BusinessTemplate();
  var model = new ModelBinder().Build(businessTemplate); // model is of type 'BusinessModel'
```